# Showing user the lists to routes he can go

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

In my app I have different roles associated to different organizations. I have three organization types for now

1. Crondale (Our inner system)
2. Kitchens
3. Institutions

An organization type can have multiple organizations like

> Kitchen having multiple kitchens (Kitchen 1, Kitchen 2 etc...)
>
> Institution having multiple kitchens (Institution 1, Institution 2 etc...)

Now the roles are like this,

Bob is an admin of organization type Kitchen and for Kitchen 1.

Up til now, everything works smoothly. Now the issue is that a user can have multiple role. So for example,

In addition of being an Admin for Kitchen 1, Bob is also Nurse at Institution 1.

Now what I want is, when the user logs in I get all the role types and then allow the user to select which one he wants to go to. If it is only one then take him directly there. But what should be done for multiples?

This is what I am doing so far,

```
public ActionResult Dashboard()
{
    User user = TableHelper.Get<User>("1", User.Identity.Name);
    
    if (user != null)
    {
        List<OrganizationValues> data = CheckOrganizationType.organizationType(user); // getting organization type
        if (data.Count() == 1) // if we have one role at a time
        {
            foreach (OrganizationValues ov in data)
            {
                if (ov.name != "crondale" && ov.name != "") // which means it doesn't belong to US!
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Dashboard", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo.ToTitleCase(ov.name), new { id = ov.organizationId, roleId = ov.roleType });
                }
                else // we are crondale
                {
                    ViewBag.rolesType = getRoles();
                    ViewBag.organizationTypes = getOrganizationTypes();
                }
            }
            return View(user);
        }
        else // you have more than 1 role
        {
        
        }
    } // if user is not logged in
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Site");
    }
}
```

Any insight on how to achieve this in the best possible way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make a single dynamic page listing the modules accessible according to the roles ? So user can choose which page they want to view.
It'll also help in case when more number of roles are added.